# C# ASP.Net MVC3, Membeship

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-membership

I am looking to check if the user has a phone or not. I'm using the asp.net Membership  to manage users, is there a way to retrieve the user's phone?

```
thank you in advance,
```

Answer (score 0):

You could evaluate the

```
Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
```

content. On my desktop it shows something like Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0).

There exist multiple "user agent lists" in the web to identify a mobile device.